# Generated files in xtext with xbase

Tags: xtext, xtend

I followed this tutorial: https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/104_jvmdomainmodel.html, but the generated files are .java, I want to change the file extension as well as the grammar, but I want to keep some java features. Also the `class DomainmodelGenerator extends AbstractGenerator` does not get generated when I use `grammar org.example.domainmodel.Domainmodel with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase`, only if I use terminals. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Xbase then, `JvmModelGenerator` will be used as `IGenerator(2)`. So you have to customize that one and override `org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.DefaultXbaseRuntimeModule.bindIGenerator()` for binding.
But also triple check if you really want to customize the generator and not enhance the inferrer

Comment: I don't have this class in any package, where do I find it?

Comment: I want to create a new file with .drl extension, with my grammar, but to include some java features such as getA().getB()... from some classes, types as well etc

Comment: at which place?

Comment: you have  to create a new generator class in a package of your choice

Comment: do you have any example/tutorial to follow?

Comment: i dont understand: simply create a class. override the method in yourdslruntimemodule and return your class